# how do i make an objects continuously spawn on kaboom.js

Tags: game-development, spawning, kaboom

When I shoot the asteriod they disapear which is what i want however I want more asteriods to spawn instead of them just disapearing forever.Im not sure what to add in this code to make more spawn into the game.

any help is appreciated

i thought making the number of asteriods a constant would make sure that 5 asteriods are on screen at all times however that didnt seem to work

```
// the asteroids

 const NUM_ASTERIODS = 3;

for (let i = 0; i < NUM_ASTERIODS; i++) {
  var spawnPoint = asteroidSpawnPoint();
  var a = add([
      sprite("asteroid"),
      pos(spawnPoint),
      rotate(rand(1,90)),
      origin("center"),
      area(),
      scale(0.2),      
      solid(),
      "asteroid",
      "mobile",
      "wraps",
      {
          speed: rand(5, 10),
          initializing: true
      }
  ]);

while (a.isColliding("mobile")) {
  spawnPoint = asteroidSpawnPoint();
  a.pos = spawnPoint;
  a.pushOutAll();
}

a.initializing = false;
  a.pushOutAll();



}

function asteroidSpawnPoint() {
   // spawn randomly at the edge of the scene
   return choose([rand(vec2(0), vec2(width(), 0)),
           rand(vec2(0), vec2(0, height())),
           rand(vec2(0, height()), vec2(width(), height())),
           rand(vec2(width(), 0), vec2(width(), height()))]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when trying to spawn continuous sprites from the top of the screen. I found the following code worked to spawn my sprites at random positions (x-axis) across the top of the screen (y-axis).

Kaboom suggests using the `wait()` method within a recursive function in their tutorial, which avoids using a loop and allows you to control the frequency of spawning.

```
 function spawnAsteroid() {
    add([sprite('asteroid'),
    pos(rand(width()), 0),
    origin(),
    body(),
    'dangerous'
    ])

    wait(rand(0.5, 1), spawnAsteroid);

  }

  spawnAsteroid();
```